# Differential topology and Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds"

Tags: soft-question, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Very soft question, is the content of [Tu's : "An Introduction to Manifolds"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xQsTJJGsgs4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=an%20introduction%20to%20manifolds&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY5oKXo53nAhVNT8AKHbVpB-IQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=an%20introduction%20to%20manifolds&f=false) what is usually covered in "differential topology"?

Comment: It looks shuffled around, but I'd say yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is a standard course on differentiable manifolds. (I do not know the book personally. The table of contents seems to be missing general vector bundles and, more important, the Frobenius Theorem.) Differential topology (as you can see from, e.g., Guillemin and Pollack's undergraduate book and Hirsch's graduate text) usually incorporates notions of transversality, intersection numbers, and their applications, say, to Euler classes of oriented vector bundles.

That said, the terms *differential geometry* and *differential topology* get bandied about quite generally to refer to standard material on differentiable manifolds —whether (in the former case) curvature and connections on bundles or (in the latter case) transversality and intersection theory are present in the courses or not.

Comment: Can you give the titles of the books you mentioned? Are you talking about these two: 1) https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=emTmBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=differential+topology&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZl86RzKPnAhWMSRUIHe2yA2YQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=differential%20topology&f=false, 2) https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FdRhAQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=differential+topology&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZl86RzKPnAhWMSRUIHe2yA2YQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=differential%20topology&f=false

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Hi Again, I skimmed through the contents of the two books and I was wondering if differential forms are actually used in this field, if yes can you point out a reference that approaches differential topology using differential forms?

Comment: More in differential geometry than in differential topology, although things like characteristic classes of smooth bundles can fall into both subjects. That said, the last chapter of G&P is all differential forms and a few applications.

Comment: The Hirsch textbook also talks about Morse Theory, which is something I'm interested in. Last chapter of G & P covers integration which is already covered in Tu's textbook.